# sRGB colorPixelFormat in Metal on macOS gives strange results

Tags: macos, colors, metal

Background: I'm trying to solve this issue in iTerm2: https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/6703#note_71933498

iTerm2 uses the default pixel format of `MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm` for all its textures, including the MTKView's drawable. On my machine, if my texture function returns a color **C** then the Digital Color Meter app in "Display in sRGB" will show that the onscreen color is **C**. I don't know why this works! It should convert the raw color values from my texture function to sRGB, causing them to change, right? For example, here's what I see when my fragment function returns `(0, 0.16, 0.20, 1)` for the window's background color:

[image: Proof that a texture with non-sRGB pixel format takes sRGB values from the fragment function]

That's weird, but I could live with it until someone complained that it didn't work on their machine (see the issue linked to above). For them, the value my fragment function returns goes through the Generic -> sRGb conversion and looks wrong. It's a hackintosh, so it could be a driver bug or something, but it prompted me to look into this more.

If I change the pixel format everywhere to `MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB` then I get colors I can't explain:

[image]

The fragment function remains unchanged, returning `(0, 0.16, 0.2, 1)`. It's rendering to a texture I created with the `MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB` pixel format (not the drawable, if it matters, although the drawable has the same pixel format) and I can see in the GPU debugger that this texture is assigned the too-bright values you see above. In this screenshot the digital color meter is showing the color of the "Intermediate Texture" thumbnail:

[image]

Here's the fragment function (modified for debugging purposes):

`fragment float4
iTermBackgroundColorFragmentShader(iTermBackgroundColorVertexFunctionOutput in [[stage_in]]) {
    return float4(0, 0.16, 0.20, 1);
}`

I also tried hacking Apple's [sample app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AdoptingMetalI/Introduction/Intro.html) (`MetalTexturedMesh`) to use the sRGB pixel format and return the same color from its fragment shader, and I got the same result. [Here is the change I made to it](https://pastebin.com/mr3zyahD). I can only conclude that I don't understand how Metal defines pixel formats, and I can't find any reasonable interpretation that would give the behavior that I see.

Comment: What are the actual byte values in your texture? (Going through the GPU debugger's preview display and the color meter introduces chances for confusion.) How do those values compare to what the color meter shows when configured to show absolute values instead of percentages?

Comment: I exported the texture from the GPU debugger to a PNG and it's (0, 110, 124). Digital color meter in sRGB mode gives (3, 110, 123). Not sure why it would differ slightly, but it's still pretty far from what I expect: (0, 41, 51).

Comment: Don't use the GPU debugger. Call one of the `MTLTexture` `-getBytes:...` methods in your app code and dump that. Don't forget to synchronize the texture back to the CPU before that. Also, when you say you expect (0, 0.16, 0.20) to become (0, 41, 51) is that with the non-sRGB pixel format?

Comment: The raw bytes are `7C 6E 00 FF` in BGRA. That's certainly not what digital color meter reported, but it's also super far from what I expect. I would have expected `33 29 00 ff`. Since the texture function is hardcoded to `return float4(0, 0.16, 0.20, 1);` and the pixel format is sRGB, I'd expect `0.2` in the blue channel to produce 0.2*255=51 (decimal) = 0x33, not 0x7c. I can also see that it's clearly much brighter than the same color drawn with without metal (e.g., in -drawRect:).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The raw bytes are `7C 6E 00 FF` in BGRA. That's certainly not what digital color meter reported, but it's also super far from what I expect.

That **is** what the color meter reported. That byte sequence corresponds to (0, 0.43, 0.49).

> I would have expected `33 29 00 ff`. Since the texture function is hardcoded to `return float4(0, 0.16, 0.20, 1);` and the pixel format is sRGB, I'd expect `0.2` in the blue channel to produce 0.2*255=51 (decimal) = 0x33, not 0x7c.

Your expectation is incorrect. Within shaders, colors are *always* linear, never sRGB. If a texture is sRGB, then reading from it converts from sRGB to linear and writing to it converts from linear to sRGB.

Given the linear (0, 0.16, 0.2) in your shader, the conversion to sRGB described in section 7.7.7 of the [Metal Shading Language spec](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364?language=objc)(PDF) would produce (0, 0.44, 0.48) for floating-point and (0, 111, 124) a.k.a. (0, 0x6f, 0x7c) for RGBA8Unorm. That's very close to what you're getting. So, the result seems correct for sRGB.

The conversion algorithm from linear to sRGB as given in the spec is:

```
if (isnan(c)) c = 0.0;
if (c > 1.0)
    c = 1.0;
else if (c < 0.0)
    c = 0.0;
else if (c < 0.0031308)
    c = 12.92 * c;
else
    c = 1.055 * powr(c, 1.0/2.4) - 0.055;
```

The conversion algorithm from sRGB to linear is:

```
if (c <= 0.04045)
    result = c / 12.92;
else
    result = powr((c + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4);
```

> I can also see that it's clearly much brighter than the same color drawn with without metal (e.g., in -drawRect:).

How did you construct the color to draw for that case? Note that the generic (a.k.a. calibrated) RGB color space is **not** linear. It has a gamma of ~1.8. Core Graphics has `kCGColorSpaceGenericRGBLinear` which is linear.

The mystery is why you see a much darker color when you use a non-sRGB texture. The hard-coded color in your shader should always represent the same color. The pixel format of the texture shouldn't affect how it ultimately shows up (within rounding error). That is, it's converted from linear to the texture's pixel format and, on display, from the texture's pixel format to the display color profile. That's transitive, so the result should be the same as going directly from linear to the display color profile.

Are you sure you aren't pulling the bytes from that texture and then interpreting them as though they were sRGB? Or maybe using `-newTextureViewWithPixelFormat:...`?

Comment: Ok, so I think I was wrong to expect that a fragment function returning `float4(0, 0.16, 0.2, 1)` would produce any particular value in the texture. What I care about is that it looks the same as:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
  [[NSColor colorWithSRGBRed:0 green:0.16 blue:0.20 alpha:1] set];
  NSRectFill(rect);
}
```

And that is clearly not happening.

Comment: OK, so an sRGB color (0, 0.16, 0.2) corresponds to a linear color (0, 0.022, 0.033). You would want your shader to return that. You can perform the computation for arbitrary sRGB values using the algorithm I've added to the answer. Or, you could manually set the sRGB bytes in an sRGB texture, pass that into your shader, and read the color from that texture in the shader. That will make Metal do the conversion.